# PHP not showing updated values in Dropdown list after submitting

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a dropdown list which is populated by php.I need to enter new values to the db using the data entered.The page is posted to itself.But the list does not show the new values inserted.

**SOURCE CODE**:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Add Product Category</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["form_974780"]["productname"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Please Enter New Product Name");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body id="main_body" >

        <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
        <div id="form_container">

            <h1><a>Add Product Category</a></h1>
            <form id="form_974780" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="?" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                        <div class="form_description">
                <h2>Add Product Category</h2>
                <p></p>
            </div>                      
                <ul >

                        <li id="li_12" >
            <label class="description" for="element_12">Existing Product Categories  </label>
            <div>
            <select class="element select medium" id="element_12" name="element_12"> 
            <?php 

   // $conn = goes here 
    $result=$conn->query("SELECT pname FROM products");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value='".$row['pname']."'>".$row['pname']."</option>";


    }
     mysqli_close($conn);
    ?> 

            </select>
            </div> 
            </li>       <li id="li_13" >
            <label class="description" for="element_13">Add New Category </label>
            <div>
                <input id="element_13" name="productname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
            </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_13"><small>Enter the new Product Category to add and Click the Add Button. </small></p> 
            </li>

                        <li class="buttons">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="974780" />

                    <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </li>
                </ul>
            </form> 

        </div>
        <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $productname=$_POST['productname'];
        //$conn string will go here 
       $result=$conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname)VALUES('$productname')");
        if($result)
        {

                    echo "<font color=\"white\">";
            echo("Successfully Inserted new Products");

            echo"</font>!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<font color=\"red\">";
            echo("Error when inserting");
            echo"</font>!";
        }
    } 
    else
    {

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You are selecting the values before you insert, thats the problem i think

Comment: Theres no insert code and after that it seems you will show your database records first and only then insert them, that won't show you the last one inserted.

Comment: @Bulk deleted code accidentally while posting,edited

Comment: @techno no problem I deleted my comment after I saw that

Comment: @techno my comment remain valid! You are retrive values from DB before you save new one on DB (if exists new one to be inserted).
Try to pass your last php code to the beggining of your file.

Comment: And check this line to:
`$result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname)VALUES('$productname')");` you are missing space nex to `VALUES`, it should be:
`$result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname) VALUES ('$productname')");`

Comment: @lmarcelocc your first comment fixed the issue,never thought that :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help you :)
Have a nice coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@techno, 
you are retrive values from DB before you save new one on DB (if exists new one to be inserted). Try to pass your last php code to the beggining of your file.
Code you should pass to beggining is:

```
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $productname=$_POST['productname'];
            //$conn string will go here 
           $result=$conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname)VALUES('$productname')");
            if($result)
            {

                        echo "<font color=\"white\">";
                echo("Successfully Inserted new Products");

                echo"</font>!";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<font color=\"red\">";
                echo("Error when inserting");
                echo"</font>!";
            }
        } 
        else
        {

        }
    ?>
```

And give a space in this line next to `VALUES`

```
$result = $conn->query("INSERT INTO products(pname) VALUES ('$productname')");
```